# Consider two linear operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$. Show that $e^{\hat{A}}e^{\hat{B}}=e^{\hat{A}+\hat{B}}e^{[\hat{A},\hat{B}]/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

> For operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$:
>    $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=\hat{A}\hat{B}-\hat{B}\hat{A} \not=0$ but
>   $[[\hat{A},\hat{B}],\hat{A}]=[[\hat{A},\hat{B}],\hat{B}]=0$
>
> Show that:
>
> $$e^{\hat{A}}e^{\hat{B}}=e^{\hat{A}+\hat{B}}e^{[\hat{A},\hat{B}]/2} \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space (1)$$

Hints:

1. Consider: $\hat{U}(t)=e^{t\hat{A}}e^{t\hat{B}}$ and show that $\frac{d}{dt}\hat{U}(t)=\hat{U}(t)e^{-t\hat{B}}\hat{A}e^{t\hat{B}}+\hat{U}(t)\hat{B}$
2. Consider $\frac{d}{dt}e^{-t\hat{B}}\hat{A}e^{t\hat{B}}$ to show that $e^{-t\hat{B}}\hat{A}e^{t\hat{B}}=[A,B]t+\hat{A}$

I verified 1. by differentiating: $\frac{d}{dt}(e^{t\hat{A}}e^{t\hat{B}})=e^{t\hat{A}}\hat{A}e^{t \hat{B}}+e^{t\hat{A}}e^{t\hat{B}}\hat{B}=e^{t\hat{A}}e^{t\hat{B}}e^{-t \hat{B}} \hat{A}e^{t\hat{B}}+e^{t\hat{A}}e^{t \hat{B}}\\=(e^{t\hat{A}}e^{t \hat{B}})(e^{-t \hat{B}}\hat{A}e^{t \hat{B}}+\hat{B})=\hat{U}(t)e^{-t\hat{B}}\hat{A}e^{t \hat{B}}+\hat{U}(t)\hat{B} \space \checkmark$

How do I show 2. though? Shouldn't it read: $e^{-t\hat{B}}\hat{A}e^{t\hat{B}}=[\color{red}{\hat{A},\hat{B}}]t+\hat{A}$?

How can I use these two hints to show $(1)$? I don't really see the connection. Does this identity have a name?

Comment: There are no $A$ and $B$ involved elsewhere so this is a type and it  should indeed read $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]$.

Comment: A derivation can be found here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164652/proof-of-weaker-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/commutator-algebra-in-exponents

Comment: @Winther Thank you! That helps me. However, I still don't see why our lecturer give us this hint: $\frac{d}{dt}e^{-t\hat{B}}\hat{A}e^{t\hat{B}}$ to show that $e^{-t\hat{B}}\hat{A}e^{t\hat{B}}=[A,B]t+\hat{A}$

Shouldn't the first part of that hint be some sort of differential equation?

Comment: Try writing $\frac{d}{dt} e^{-tB}Ae^{tB} = e^{-tB}[A,B]e^{tB} = [A,B]$ since $[A,B]$ commutes with $B$. Note that $\frac{d}{dt}e^{-tB} = -Be^{-tB} = -e^{-tB}B$. From $\frac{df(t)}{dt} = [A,B]$ you can integrate using that at $t=0$ we have $f(0) = A$.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for your help. I am sorry if this is trivial stuff but I don't understand how you arrived at $e^{-tB}[A,B]e^{tb}=[A,B]$. If I calculate $\frac{d}{dt}e^{-tB}Ae^{tB}$ then I get $-e^{-tB}BAe^{tB}$. And how are you getting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=[A,B]$?

Comment: With $E = e^{Bt}$ we have $\frac{d}{dt}[E^{-1}AE] = [\frac{d}{dt}E^{-1}] AE + E^{-1}A[\frac{dE}{dt}] = [-E^{-1}B]AE + E^{-1}A[BE] = E^{-1}[AB - BA]E$. The derivative is over the whole expression not just the first term. We can now simplify $E^{-1}[A,B]E = E^{-1}E[A,B] = [A,B]$ since $[A,B]$ and $B$ commutes, $[[A,B],B] = 0$ so $[A,B]E = [A,B](1 + B + B^2/2 + \ldots) = (1 + B + B^2/2 + \ldots)[A,B]$.

Comment: @Winther I thought the derivative just applied to the first term. I went through the calculation and I get the same result as you. There are still three things I don't understand though. Why is $$e^{-tB}[A,B]e^{tB}=[A,B]$$? How are you defining $f(t)$? Is it $f(t)=e^{-tB}Ae^{tB}$? Why does $e^{tB}B=Be^{tB}$? Do I treat $e^{tB}$ like a constant?

Comment: $[[A,B],B] = 0$ just says that $[A,B]B = B[A,B]$ which leads to $[A,B]B^n = B^n[A,B]$ for any integer $n$ (by induction for example). Now $[A,B]e^{B} = [A,B](1 + B + B^2/2 + \ldots)$ and by the previous result $[A,B]$ commutes with all the terms in the power-series. Note that this is a general result if $[X,Y] = 0$ then $f(X) Y = Yf(X)$. I can try to write it up as an answer if that is better.

Comment: @Winther That's a great explanation, thanks! It is slowly starting to make sense. Does [A,B] also commute with all the terms of the power series of $e^{-B}$? Wouldn't my first term be a $-1$? In case it does then I have $\frac{d f(t)}{dt}=[A,B] \iff \int f(t)dt=\int [A,B]dt \iff f(t)=[A,B]t+c$. From my original equation I get $f(0)=e^{0}Ae^{0}=A \implies f(t)=[A,B]t+A$. Plugging this into the equation I got in 1. $\implies \frac{d U}{dt}=U([A,B]t+A+B)$

Comment: @Winther I can separate the variables and solve that differential equation: $$\int \frac{dU}{u}=\int [A,B]t+A+B \\ \iff \ln{U=[A,B]\frac{t^2}{2}}+At+Bt \\ \iff U=e^{[A,B]t^2/2}e^{(A+B)t}=e^{tA}e^{tB}$$
For $n=1$ I have proved it. (with a lot of your help. Thanks!)

Comment: Looks good! The only thing I can critizice is the integration. The trick you use $U' = fU \implies \int dU/U = \int f dt$ is only really valid when $U$ is a real-valued function and not a matrix like here (the matrix does not have to be invertible for example). The way you (and myself often) do it usually leads to the correct solution though. See e.q. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) for more info about solving such matrix ODEs.

Comment: @Winther Thanks. I will check out the wikipedia explanation. I wanted to ask on last thing. Do I get $e^{-tB}[A,B]e^{tB}=[A,B]$ because I can write the expression like this $e^{-tB}e^{tB}[A,B]$ cancelling out the exponential functions or because of the commutation $[A,B]e^{tB}=e^{-tB}[A,B]=0$?

Comment: It's because $e^{-tB}[A,B]e^{tB} = e^{-tB}e^{tB}[A,B]$ and $e^{-tB}e^{tB} = 1$. With $X = tB$, $Y = [A,B]$ and $f(X) = e^{X}$ we have $[X,Y] = 0$ so by the result in my answer $Yf(X) = f(X)Y$. We don't have $e^{-tB}[A,B] = 0$ though.

Comment: @Winther Sorry the "$=0$" part was actually a typo (it's getting late here). It makes sense now. Thanks again for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are trying to prove is a special case of the [Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) formula:

$$e^{A+B} = e^Ae^B e^{-\frac{[A,B]}{2!}}e^{\frac{2[B,[A,B]] + [A,[A,B]]}{3!}}\cdots$$

---

We start with a small fact that will be useful below:

> If $f$ is an analytic function and $[X,Y] = 0$ then $Yf(X) = f(X)Y$

The proof is simple: By induction $[X,Y] = 0$ implies $[X^n,Y] = 0$ for any integer $n$. Next write $f$ as a power-series and use that $Y$ commutes with every term in the series
$$Yf(X) = Y(a_0 + a_1X + a_2 X^2 +\ldots) = (a_0 + a_1X + a_2 X^2 + \ldots)Y = f(X)Y$$

---

You show 2) by evaluating and simplifying the derivative and then integrating it up again. By the chain-rule we have

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-Bt}Ae^{Bt}\right) = \left(\frac{d}{dt}e^{-Bt}\right)Ae^{Bt} + e^{-Bt}A\left(\frac{d}{dt}e^{Bt}\right)$$
We further have $\frac{d}{dt}e^{B} = Be^{B} = e^{B}B$ (since $B$ commutes with $B$) which gives us
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-Bt}Ae^{Bt}\right) = e^{-Bt}(-BA)e^{Bt} + e^{-Bt}(AB)e^{Bt} = e^{-Bt}[A,B]e^{Bt}$$
Finally since $[A,B]$ commutes with $B$ ($[[A,B],B] = 0$) the result above gives us 
$$[A,B]e^{Bt} = e^{Bt}[A,B]$$ 
which leads to the desired result
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-Bt}Ae^{Bt}\right) = e^{-Bt}[A,B]e^{Bt} = e^{-Bt}e^{Bt}[A,B] = [A,B]$$
since $e^{-tB}e^{tB} = e^{-tB+tB} = e^0 = 1$ (this fact the same as the result you are trying to show the simpler case when $[A,B] = 0$, i.e. $e^{A}e^{B} = e^{A+B}$). Integrating up we find
$$e^{-Bt}Ae^{Bt} = C + t[A,B]$$

where $C = A$ is determined by taking $t=0$.

---

Using the two hints we get

$$\frac{d}{dt}U(t) = U(t)(A + t[A,B]) + U(t)B = U(t)(A + B + t[A,B])$$

Integrating up and taking $U(0) = 1$ gives us

$$U(t) = e^{At}e^{Bt} = e^{At + Bt + \frac{t^2[A,B]}{2}}$$

which for $t=1$ is the result we are after. Another option to integrating is simply differentiating $e^{At + Bt + \frac{t^2[A,B]}{2}}$ and show that it satisfies the same ODE as $U(t)$ and has the same value $1$ at $t=0$.

Comment: You posted an answer 1 minute before I was going to post an answer in the comments. :) Thank you very much. I couldn't have completed the problem without your help. I think I learned more in the last hour than in two lectures combined.